# How can I find the most highly-rated Netflix movies?

Tags: netflix

"Recommended for you" seems to list all movies according to your personalized rating, but I'm interested in the global rating toplist (similar to IMDB's Top250). There's also a Netflix Top 100 that's based on rental throughput, not rating. There are some websites that have Netflix toplists but they are restricted to the subset of movies that are available on the streaming service. I want to see the non-streamable movies too.

Is this list available? If it is not officially listed on the website, perhaps somebody mined all the data recently.

Answer (score 2):

[This third-party website](http://www.bestonnetflix.com/best/movies) lists all of Netflix's movies (and TV series if you are interested) in order of rating. However, it is only for Netflix shows available in the USA and Canada, and so other countries may have different movies and ratings.

**EDIT:** I missed the part of the non-streaming movies. I'm unsure if there exists any website with ratings for these.